# Perl DBI, How to fetch fields from mysql table of ENUM datatype?

Tags: perl

I know how to fetch all fields using the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table_name';
```

but not sure how to fetch only the fields that have been assigned the `ENUM` `datatype` when the table was created.

I found an answer:

```
my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", "$db_user", "$db_pwd") or die (print "Can't connect to database $DBI::errstr<br>");

my $sth = $dbh->column_info(undef,undef,'table_name','%') or die $dbh->errstr();

while(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()){

if ($row->{TYPE_NAME} eq 'ENUM') {
    push(@list, $row->{COLUMN_NAME});
}
}  

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: post your answer actually as an answer, not part of the question, and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect a table using [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html).  I would not recommend running that query every time that you want to pull data from the table though.

```
my @enums = ();
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{DESC } . $tablename);
$sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;
while (my $hashref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    push @enums, $hashref->{Field} if $hashref->{Type} =~ /^enum/;
}
$sth->finish; undef $sth;
```